# Make fieldset fit its enclosing div

Tags: html, css

## The code:

#### The HTML

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

#### The CSS

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

---

## The Problem: The fieldset does not fit the div

How do I go about having the fieldset not exceed the size of the div?

For instance if I set the size of the div with CSS, it makes no difference as to how much space the fieldset will occupy.

---

How to go about this?

---

## EDIT

I would like to have two options to solve this:

one, having scroll functionality in the div

and two, having the text break up in to a new line inside the fieldset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this css code:

```
div {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Fix this issue:

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <fieldset> 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: have you fixed this issue?

Comment: try <fieldset><div>aaaaaaaaa</div></fieldset> then set word-wrap for <div> element

Comment: that does not work, either. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/KermitTheHermit/9sxjwq46/

Comment: I've edited my answer, try these code and let me know if you have trouble again

Comment: Did you have to put the div inside the fieldset?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to find the reason why word-wrap doesn't work with fieldset

Comment: If all else fails, I will resort to swapping the div and fieldset. However I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Great, that did it! I appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer before I accept, just to prevent potential confusion, to make it clear what I'm actually accepting? Or should I edit?

Comment: Please make it clear for me because my english is not so good :D Thanks

Comment: I recommend placing `word-break: break-all;` on the `fieldset` element in the event that you have other text element sinside your container that you do not want breaking word.

Answer (score 1):

You just need `word-break: break-all;` on your container or `fieldset` element.

**Edited:** Added `overflow: auto;` to container element so it scrolls since it has a fixed height.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

fieldset {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <fieldset>
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kermit the Hermit - I see that you wanted scrolling. I edited my answer to include that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the fieldset to exceed the fixed size of it's parent, then you'll have to allow it to have scrollbars:

```
div { width: 200px; height: 100px; }
fieldset { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: I thought the same @Adam but I think he wants to break the text if is too long.

Comment: @AlexChar - I'm thinking most people misunderstood the OP - this is the  part of the question that stood out to me: `How do I go about having the fieldset not exceed the size of the div?`

Comment: @Adam for some reason it doesn't give me scrollbars, it looks the same as before.

Comment: @AlexChar I would actually like to solve this both ways, by breaking the string up and by adding scroll functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing here is due to the fact that your test string "aaa" does not contain spaces so is not broken with line returns so the fieldset width is expanded.

Idealy you should test your layout with words such as "lorem ipsum" templates.